# Problem with deploying Go app to Google App Engine

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-go

I developed my first Go app and decided to deploy it to Google Cloud (App Engine). It was running perfectly fine locally but I run into a few issues during the deployment (I'm using Cloud SDK).

I eventually got to the point where I was able to successfully deploy it to GCP but I keep getting

[image: 500 error]

when trying to access the app.

I cannot do any local development either because every time I run `go run main.go`, `go get -u`, `go build` I'm getting:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql
go: found github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql in github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy v0.0.0-20200513164142-a9864b03c326
go: github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy@v0.0.0-20200513164142-a9864b03c326 requires
        cloud.google.com/go@v0.56.0 requires
        cloud.google.com/go/bigquery@v1.4.0 requires
        cloud.google.com/go@v0.52.0 requires
        cloud.google.com/go/bigquery@v1.0.1/go.mod: verifying module: cloud.google.com/go/bigquery@v1.0.1/go.mod: cannot authenticate record data in server response
```

My `go.mod` file looks like this:

```
module swanson

go 1.14

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.4
```

and this is the structure of my app (`main.go`, `models`, and `router` are 3 different packages):

[image: structure]

I'm new to Go development and never deployed a Go app to GCP so feeling quite lost, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app

Answer (score 0):

I have tried deploying a go application in app engine and also running it locally and both worked.

I used 
[this application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine/go11x/helloworld)
 in github, which you can clone with the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples
```

The command I have used for running the application locally is :

```
go run helloworld.go
```

And the command returned the following message:

```
2020/05/22 11:34:16 Defaulting to port 8080
2020/05/22 11:34:16 Listening on port 8080
```

Then in the Cloud Shell I have opened the web preview in the port 8080 and it was working as expected.

For more information about the deployment, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/testing-and-deploying-your-app).